# Reminders - Open List in New Window

Tags: applescript

I would like to update the following AppleScript code to open one of my Reminders lists in a new window.

Any suggestions? Thx Gianandrea

```
tell application "System Events" to tell process "Reminders"
  click menu item "Open List in New Window" of menu 1 of menu bar item "Window" of menu bar 1
 click menu item "Reminders" of menu 1 of menu bar item "Window" of menu bar 1>
end tell
```